# Spring MVC point to host name

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I'm setting up a Spring MVC project for my own knowledge and I'm hitting a bit of a bump.  I have a welcome file and a web service set up and they work pretty nicely.  However, instead of localhost:8080/ZFGC/ hitting the welcome file, I'd like localhost:8080/ to hit it.  From there, I want to be able to call my web services in a similar manner, i.e. without the ZFGC/.  I haven't been able to find a tutorial that actually explains this properly.  Could someone enlighten me?

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>zfgc</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>zfgc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zfgc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/index.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ZFGC</groupId>
  <artifactId>ZFGC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>ZFGC</name>
  <description>Zelda Fan Game Central</description>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

zfgc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.zfgc.forum.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

[image: directory structure:]

Comment: What is the Runtime environment you're using to run the application? `mvn jetty:run` or `tomcat`?

Comment: @user1354678 Tomcat 8

Comment: Did you run it like this in eclipse? ProjectName -> Run As -> Run on Server? then choosing tomcat.. OR did you put your application inside tomcat's webapp directory and starting startup.bat..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running the application inside eclipse (by tomcat), it's just a one step configuration.

Follow the Steps. (Be sure to stop tomcat before doing this)

1) You'll find a Folder as "Servers" in Project list displayed in eclipse.

2) Expand **Servers -> Tomcat v8.0**

3) You'll see list of configuration files. Open **server.xml**

4) Scoll to the bottom. You'll see a line which will be like this,

```
<Context docBase="ZFGC" path="/ZFGC" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ZFGC"/>
```

5) Now simply change that line to this

```
<Context docBase="ZFGC" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ZFGC"/>
```

and save the changes.

To mention accurately, `path="/ZFGC"` is changed to `path="/"` . That's it. Now start your tomcat and you can access your application in http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Beautiful.  And it looks like the answer below yours also covers how to do it without eclipse.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MGZero, yup. That'll help you if you want to run your application outside eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

To hit your app with http://localhost:8080 the only thing you need to do is deploy your web application as the ROOT application in your Application Server.

That basically consists on naming your WAR file `ROOT.war`

In Maven you can do it easily using:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    <outputDirectory>war</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</plugins>
```